# Multiple parameterized metrics in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, metrics

Let's say I have a custom parameterized metric:

```
def my_metric_at_k(k):

    def my_metric(y_true, y_pred):

        '''
        Do magic here with k
        to get metric_value
        '''

        return metric_value

    return my_metric
```

I want to evaluate my model with my metric on multiple values of `k`, say `k=1` and `k=2`, so naturally, I'm inclined to feed `[my_metric_at_k(1), my_metric_at_k(2)]` into `metrics` input of the `compile` method.

When I go to fit my model, I run into this error

> NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node metrics/my_metric_1/...: not found

I'm using Keras with a TensorFlow backend.

For a particular example, one metric I use is the following:

```
def variety_first_k(k):
    def variety(y_true, y_pred):

        y_pred = K.tf.cast(y_pred, dtype=K.tf.float64)
        sort = K.tf.nn.top_k(y_pred, k=k, sorted=True).indices

        unique, _ = K.tf.unique(K.flatten(sort))

        num_unique = K.shape(unique)[0]

        return K.tf.cast(num_unique, dtype=K.tf.float64) / 
               K.tf.cast(K.tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype=K.tf.float64)

    return variety
```

I'm running a multi-label multi-class problem.

A simplified version of my model is:

```
metrics = [variety_first_k(1), variety_first_k(2)]

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(my_data.shape[1],))

merged_layer = layers.BatchNormalization()(inputs)
merged_layer = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=0.5, l2=0.5))(merged_layer)

merged_layer = layers.BatchNormalization()(merged_layer)
predictions = layers.Dense(len(mlb.classes_))(merged_layer)
predictions = layers.Activation('sigmoid')(predictions)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

EPOCHS = 100
INIT_LR = 1e-2
BS = 128

opt = keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)

model.compile(loss=multilabel,
              optimizer=opt, 
              metrics=metrics)

H = model.fit(x=my_data, 
              y=Y,
              validation_split=0.02,
              epochs=EPOCHS, 
              batch_size=BS)
```

The result gives me:

```
Train on 260563 samples, validate on 5318 samples
Epoch 1/100
...
...
NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node metrics/...: not found
```

Comment: Can you share your model and metric code? I tried running a basic example with your code, passing `[my_metric_at_k(1), my_metric_at_k(2)] ` works fine for me.

Comment: Updated! Please see my question again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error while using your code. I'm not sure what could be the cause... What version of Keras are you running?

Comment: Ha! I just realized I had branched way off my tf graph and there were memory caches that were causing conflicts. After restarting my kernel and resetting my graph, it now works. Thank you for the help, however!